# Copying Trello cards from one board to another

Tags: trello, trello-cards, trello-organization

This is how I copy a card from one board to another:

1. Click the card
2. Click Copy
3. Select the right board from the (long!) list of boards
4. Select the list in destination board
5. Click copy

And this I have to repeat for every card - which is quite cumbersome and error-prone.

**Is there a better way?**

Maybe I could do this in bulk somehow? Or just drag-drop between boards?

---

#### Background

In my company, we use Trello for project management of software development in sprints.

We have several boards with backlogs (for different projects) and then a board with a "current sprint", which are the tasks we work on currently.

Every week, when we pick cards from the backlog, I have to copy them over to the current sprint board. The process is slow, frustrating and error-prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a real bummer that Trello does not support bulk actions, I don't think it's an uncommon use case. My opinion aside, I can offer you two suggestions.

**Copy and Paste Shortcut**

Yep, it's as easy as that.

1. Hover your mouse over a card on Board A
2. <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
3. Hover your mouse over `Add a card...` on a list on Board B
4. <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

Here's how that works in action

[image: Trello Copy and Paste]

**Multi-select for Trello**

If you are using Google Chrome, you can buy a license for [Multiselect for Trello](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multiselect-for-trello/jlnfnpelianecpjoeahaeihmkhnkakof) a Chrome extension that makes batch actions on Trello easy.

You would

1. Select a few cards you want to move from Board A
2. Click the Actions menu and Copy
3. Select your destination Board and list from the menu

Here's that in action

[image: Multiselect for Trello Copy and Paste]

Comment: This does not work.